# Advanced custom field wordpress plugin not updating content

Tags: wordpress

I'm using the advanced custom field plugin on my site. I'm updating the content from the admin section but it is showing the old content in both, front end and back end.It doesn't show any error. I have updated the plugin but error is still there.

```
Plugin:Advance custom field  4.3
Wordpress : 3.5.1
```

Please let me know how can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you display your custom field in front end? show us the code you are using

Comment: sorry but main issue in admin section. I'm updating the content ie. in custom field from the admin section after update it is showing the old content in there also in front page also checked the database but it is same.

Comment: okey. If you are using this plugin for the first time and you dont have many posts yet, try using More Fields plugin, I am using it in my website with no issues.

Comment: I have created 19 custom fields and used them in wpsc-post type(product page). I'm using the woocommerce plugin

Comment: In this case, I think It is better to continue with Advance custom field and digg more for a solution to your problem.I am sorry I never used Woocommerce and I didnt find solution for you. I give an upvote to bring more attention to your matter